# How do I apply the Lowercase action to a line movement?

Tags: cursor-motions, normal-mode

From the [vim-as-language](https://benmccormick.org/2014/07/02/learning-vim-in-2014-vim-as-language/) article:

> Vim’s "verbs" mostly fall into 2 main categories. Some of them act on a single character, and others act on a "motion" or "text object".

And from the vim wiki for [switching the case of characters](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switching_case_of_characters):

> Toggle case `"HellO"` to `"hELLo"` with `g~` then a movement.
>   Uppercase `"HellO"` to `"HELLO"` with `gU` then a movement.
>   Lowercase `"HellO"` to `"hello"` with `gu` then a movement.

In this case, it seems like `Lowercase` is the **action**. Would "the current line" be considered a movement or text object?

For example given the line (with my cursor at the `|`):

```
pgp - Pretty Good Privac|y
```

I'm wondering use the action-movement pattern to "downcase the current line" works in this case. I used `gu0` which worked.

But what if the cursor is in the middle of the line like:

```
pgp - Pretty Go|od Privacy
```

Then, `gu0` followed by `gu$` will work, but it seems "the current line" should be a text-object. I also used `guk` or `guk` which works but I'm not sure if I'm thinking about the pattern the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gugu` or `guu` for making current line lowercase. There's no a text object for current line

You can also use `guip` or `guis` which stand for paragraph and for sentence text objects

Comment: why does `gugu` and `guu` work?

Comment: Repeating the command to make it act on the entire current line is a common idiom in vim.  `yy`, `dd`, etc. all work this way.